# Firebase login callback with Polymer

Tags: javascript, callback, firebase, polymer

I'm building a Polymer app that uses the `firebase-auth` element for authentication. I'm using the `password` provider and a callback method for the `on-login` property. The callback method is set to log to console when called for testing purposes. If I load the page while already logged in, I see a single log line in the console, indicating that the `on-login` callback is also called when the element re-attaches to an existing session, not just when a new login is done. When I log in manually however, I see the log line in the console twice, indicating that my callback is being referenced twice.

1) Why is it being called twice? Is there a way to only have it called once?

2) Is there a way to bind a callback to the login action, not subsequent page loads? I could call the callback method from my own code that submits the login, but this doesn't take into account failed logins.

---

### Code, at request:

#### index.html

```
<firebase-auth id="auth" user="{{user}}" status-known="{{statusKnown}}" location="https://my-app.firebaseio.com/" provider="password" on-login="onLogin" on-error="onLoginError" on-logout="onLogout"></firebase-auth>
```

#### app.coffee

```
app.onLogin = (e) ->
  console.log "Logged in user #{app.user.uid}."
```

Comment: Please post your code, not a description of it.

Comment: I generally post code snippets, but as you can see by the two above, the description provides the same necessary details in a similar number of characters, and the question isn't so much "why doesn't my code work", but rather "what is the way to call a method for X action?". Three line of very generic code feel trivial to post. Either way, code posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being solved the way it was asked: in two parts.

1) This was actually a bug in the `firebase-auth` element. It was resolved in commit [37d1f69](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/commit/37d1f69293f8dd37fa63ff9796fe6cde7c46d55a#diff-2eb10d852da705af9bafbcd8f6dc9d7d).

2) For my purposes, I built a workaround that uses a flag (normally `false`) that gets set to `true` when a login is called and set back to `false` once consumed by a conditional within the callback.